# Taglib flac Cover

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, taglib, flac

Hi when I try to get the album cover from a flac file using Taglib I get this error

> Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Even though I know that the flac file contains an image.
I'm using this code:

```
TagLib.File f = TagLib.File.Create(path); 
if(f.Tag.Pictures.Length == 0) return;
var bin = (byte[])(f.Tag.Pictures[0].Data.Data);
songData.Cover = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(bin));
```

The code works with mp3 files but not with flac. 
So how do I get the album cover in c#?

Edit: I have found out that the code work with some flac files but not with all?

Comment: How about checking the length of the array before accessing it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access element of array you should always check if it's not null and if it contains any element:

```
TagLib.File f = TagLib.File.Create(path);
if(f.Tag.Pictures != null && f.Tag.Pictures.Length != 0)
{
    var bin = (byte[])(f.Tag.Pictures[0].Data.Data);
    songData.Cover = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(bin));
}
```

Comment: Yes I know but that's not the problem the problem is that it don't find the picture even though I know there is one.

Comment: By using any media program with support for flac files like vlc media player or foobar2000

Comment: @Kyeman I think that your flac file don't have picture, probably you have some .jpg files in your folder where is your flac file and this file is loaded by media program.

Comment: flac files does support Pictures